# Hows uninstall express (in order to install a previous version)

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I want to downgrade the the express version from 4.0.0 to 3.4.4 installed globally.
So I tried with sudo aslo:

```
Simo$ npm uninstall express npm 
      WARN uninstall not installed in
      /node-dev/DaysApp/node_modules: "express"
```

And globally:

```
Simo$ sudo npm uninstall -g express 
      Password: 
      npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "express"
```

And I changed the express dependencies version in the package.json to 3.4.4 and did `$ npm install` and also `$ npm install express@3.4.4` . But the vesion still 4.0.0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you know the version is still 4?

Comment: I tape in the command line: ...DaysApp Simo$ express --version
and the answer is: 4.0.0

Comment: Try typing "which express" to see which Express if finding and from where.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/express